# Implement errorhandler in WCF with IoC

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm trying to implement an errorhandler on my WCF service following this tutorial:
[Implementing IErrorHandler](http://www.neovolve.com/2008/04/07/implementing-ierrorhandler/)
In this errorhandler I want every exception to log into a logfile, by passing my logger, implementing ILogger (using by NLog in my case).

The problem now is that I want to use dependency injection, with the logger as a constructor parameter, initialized by my IoC container (using SimpleInjector).

Anybody who can help me with this? (FYI... I'm quite new with DI and IoC)

**ErrorHandler:**

```
public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ErrorHandler(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = new ErrorHandler(_logger);

        foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            var channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;

            if (channelDispatcher != null)
            {
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        _logger.Error("EXCEPTION: ", error);
        return true;
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        // Shield the unknown exception
        FaultException faultException = new FaultException("Server error encountered. All details have been logged.");
        MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();

        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, faultException.Action);
    }
}
```

**ErrorHandlerElement:**

```
public class ErrorHandlerElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ErrorHandlerElement(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new ErrorHandler(_logger);
    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(ErrorHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

Same as in tutorial, but with my own type in the behaviorExtension

**Global.asax.cs**

Creates the SimpleInjector container and registers the types

Comment: Could you provide your code (service, behavior, errorhandler, config)? It would be esier anyway.

Comment: Did you see the [docs](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wcfintegration.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the complete answer for you because I don't know Windsor. I have done this using Unity by utilizing the build policy extensions. I think Windsor have something similar.

See http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/unity-wcf-service-resolution-container-extension/ details on how to use Build Policies together with WCF.

Below is a snippet that I used to be able to configure the service host before resolving. The code enables configuration and adding of service endpoints and behaviors as interfaces that on host resolution will be resolved through the container.

Be aware that I typically don't use the app.config or equivalents.

```
public class WcfServiceHostBuildPlanPolicy<TInterface, TImplementation> : IBuildPlanPolicy
    where TInterface : class
    where TImplementation : class, TInterface
{
    private class ServiceEndpoint
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public Binding Binding { get; set; }
        public Type Type { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly List<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints;
    private readonly List<Type> behaviors;

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new service behavior.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddBehavior<T>() where T : IServiceBehavior
    {
        behaviors.Add(typeof (T));
    }

    public void AddServiceEndpoint(Type type, string address, Binding binding)
    {
        endpoints.Add(new ServiceEndpoint
        {
            Address = address,
            Binding = binding,
            Type = type
        });

    }

    public WcfServiceHostBuildPlanPolicy()
    {
        m_Behaviors = new List<Type>();
        m_Endpoints = new List<ServiceEndpoint>();
    }

    public void BuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Existing == null)
        {
            // build up dependencies
            var behavior = context.NewBuildUp<DIServiceBehavior<TInterface, TImplementation>>();

            // create new DIServiceHost
            var serviceHost = new DIServiceHost<TInterface, TImplementation>(behavior);

            // add behaviors to ServiceHost
            foreach (var behaviorType in behaviors)
            {
                var newBehavior = context.NewBuildUp(new NamedTypeBuildKey(behaviorType)) as IServiceBehavior;
                serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(newBehavior);
            }

            // add service endpoints to ServiceHost
            endpoints.ForEach(s => serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(s.Type, s.Binding, s.Address));

            context.Existing = serviceHost;
        }
    }
}
```